# BSpline vs natural spline

Tags: fitting, interpolation, splines, smoothing

The BSpline in mathematica is defined mathematically [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html). These BSplines constitute basis for any Spline. But how do I define natural splines in mathematica, i.e. splines that are linear left of the leftmost knot and right of the rightmost knot?

How can I perform generalized linear regression with natural splines?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any more detail that you could add to your question?

Comment: My expectation was that because natural splines are so common they should have had a default implementation.